# erb file with chef syntax

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, erb

Trying to output the contents of

```
node['a'] = {:b "1" :c "2"}
```

by doing this:

```
a: 
<% a = node['a'] %>
 b: <% a[:b] %>
 c: <% a[:c] %>
<% end %>
```

to generate this:

```
a: 
 b: 1
 c: 2
```

However not entirely sure the correct syntax to do this being new to ruby, chef and erb.

Comment: Are you trying to generate Yaml for a conf file?

Comment: @coderanger yes. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so let's rewind a bit. The first thing is that you generally don't want to reference node attributes directly in templates. In some cases like attributes coming from Ohai it can be okay as a shorthand, but for important data I would also pass it in via the `variables` property like this:

```
template '/etc/whatever.conf' do
  source 'whatever.conf.erb'
  variables a: node['a']
end
```

With that in place we've now expose the data as a template variable. The second piece of improving this is to let Ruby do the heavy lifting of generating YAML. We can do this using the `.to_yaml` method in the template:

```
<%= @a.to_yaml %>
```

That should be all you need!

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately it has to be done by referencing the node attribute directly in the template. Is there a way to do it directly in the template? I take it my syntax isn't quite correct. Again thanks for your help.

Comment: Sure, you could do `<%= node['a'].to_hash.to_yaml %>` in the same way but we really don't recommend it as it leads to very difficult-to-maintain cookbooks.

Comment: Thanks, I don't fully understand. This is an example of things that are in my .yml.erb file: d: <%= node ['d'] %> (where node['d'] = '5'), I need to do something similar in the .yml.erb file that will let me pull out the values of node['a'] = {:b "1" :c "2"}. I'm struggling with how to access :b and :c. Thanks

Comment: You don't, let `to_yaml` handle all of that.

Comment: Basically generating file formats like YAML and JSON is best left to libraries, just get the data structure you want in Ruby and then feed it to `to_yaml`. In this case the data you want is probably `node['whatever'].to_hash`.